# Rails validation error message not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add a custom error message for my model validation. Seen below:

```rb
validates :cost, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, message: :custom_error }
```

My en.yml looks like this:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        custom_error: "some error translation"
```

From everything I have read that should work. However, it only works in some cases. If I do the following it seems to work:

```rb
a = Item.new
a.valid? 
 # false
a.errors.messages
 # { :cost=>["some error translation"]}
```

In a rescue block I am catching that error and printing the message as seen here:

```rb
def subtract_costs
  item.cost: -10
  item.valid?
  puts "error: #{item.errors.messages}"
  # Above outputs "error: {:cost=>["some error translation"]}"
rescue StandardError => error
  puts error.message
  # Above outputs "Validation failed:"
end
```

That message is always coming out to `Validation failed:`  . Does anyone know what could be causing the error message to be blank? I do not have any other locals or translations in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I was able to find out that it wasn't related to custom error messages and instead the lack of `errors.full_messages` always being empty which affected every type of validation error (possibly other types of errors as well).

Once I dug into that method I found that it was being overridden by the gem `dynamic_form`. I was able to remove the gem and that fixed the issue. I now see all error messages being returned properly.

Comment: Dang, that is a tricky issue. Glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I see there is another issue here.
Your rescue block is a bit confusing. During your rescue block, you've rescued a Rails runtime error, not a Model validation error (unless you've used `#save!` or `#update!` which turn a model validation error into a runtime error by raising it).
So `error` in that context is a runtime error that is not designed to carry model validation error verbiage.

So you've created a situation were "it doesn't work" but in that situation it is not supposed to work. This should make it clearer:

```
def subtract_costs
  item.cost = -10
  item.valid?
  puts "error: #{item.errors.messages}" # outputs "error: {:cost=>["some error translation"]}"
  puts item.errors.class.name
rescue StandardError => error
  puts error.message # outputs "Validation failed:"
  puts error.class.name
end
```

---

You're not looking up the EN locale message properly.
You'd do it like this:

```
validates :cost,
          numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0,
                          message: I18n.t('activerecord.errors.messages.custom_error') }
```

Now there are ways to avoid even having to set the message on the validator at all, but you need to get the message in the correct place.
Here is the correct place/hierarchy in your EN locale file. This is the correct place for your specific message:

```
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      greater_than_or_equal_to: 'some error translation'
```

And in general, here are where to put custom validation error messages (and my preferred verbiage).

```
en:
  errors:
    format: "%{message}"
    messages:
      accepted:                 "The %{attribute} was not accepted; please accept the %{attribute}."
      blank:                    "The provided %{attribute} is blank; please enter a non-blank %{attribute}."
      confirmation:             "The provided %{attribute} does not match the corresponding entry; please re-check this entry against the original."
      empty:                    "The provided %{attribute} is empty; please enter a non-empty %{attribute}."
      equal_to:                 "The provided %{attribute} is incorrect; please enter exactly %{count}."
      even:                     "The provided %{attribute} is odd; please enter an even %{attribute}."
      exclusion:                "The provided %{attribute} is reserved; please enter a different %{attribute}."
      greater_than:             "The provided %{attribute} is too small; please provide a different %{attribute} greater than %{count}."
      greater_than_or_equal_to: "The provided %{attribute} is too small; please provide a different %{attribute} greater than or equal to %{count}."
      inclusion:                "The chosen %{attribute} is not available; please choose an available option." # Rails 4 and prior.
      inclusion_of:             "The chosen %{attribute} is not available; please choose an available option." # Rails 5 and later.
      invalid:                  "The provided %{attribute} is invalid; please enter a valid %{attribute}."
      in_between:               "The provided %{attribute} is outside of the accepted range; please enter a different %{attribute} within the range of %{min} to %{max}."
      less_than:                "The provided %{attribute} is too large; please provide a different %{attribute} less than %{count}."
      less_than_or_equal_to:    "The provided %{attribute} is too large; please provide a different %{attribute} less than or equal to %{count}."
      not_a_number:             "The provided %{attribute} is not numeric; please enter a numeric %{attribute}."
      odd:                      "The provided %{attribute} is even; please enter an odd %{attribute}."
      record_invalid:           "The %{attribute} is invalid. %{errors}"
      spoofed_media_type:       "The provided %{attribute} is invalid (often due to an incorrect file extension); please provide a valid %{attribute}, including an appropriate file extension."
      too_long:                 "The provided %{attribute} contains more than the %{count} available characters; please shorten the entry."
      too_short:                "The provided %{attribute} contains fewer than the %{count} required characters; please lengthen the entry."
      taken:                    "The provided %{attribute} is already taken; please enter a different %{attribute}."
      wrong_length:             "The provided %{attribute} contains the wrong amount of characters; please adjust the entry to exactly %{count} characters."
```

Comment: Thanks but I just tried that and having the same issue still. I believe you are right about the format and it is grabbing the right translation. It just isn't being returned in the `error.message`

Comment: @xxcellerator Thank you for the input. See my edit above.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I never realize rescue had that behavior. Is there a way to rescue (or error handle better) so that I can get that validation message?

Comment: It might help if you explain a bit more about what you're trying to accomplish. It's extremely rare to need to do what you're asking to do. But if you could explain your process a bit more I might be able to help. For example, what is raising this `StandardError` that you're rescuing from? Are you maybe using `#save!` when you should be using `#save`? Either way, some more details could help.

Comment: I am just trying to catch the error and return the validation message to the user who called the api. The error that is being raised is a `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid`. I updated the rescue block to look at just that error class and it is still not working. I get the same issue whether I use `save!` or `update!`. I tried switching to the `save` and `valid?` methods of checking and raising an error. However, in both cases when I dig into the error via `item.errors.messages` I get `{:cost=>["must be greater than or equal to 0"]}` but if I do `item.errors.full_messages` I get `[]`.

Comment: Avoid `#save!` and `#update!`. Those throw runtime errors when validations fail. There is no reason to do that here. Next, do not `rescue` because you're no longer throwing any runtime errors. You want to use `#save` and `#update` only. Then check if there are any errors on the model. If so, then report them back to the user. However it is very strange that `item.errors.messages` gives you errors but  `item.errors.full_messages` is somehow empty. The only thing I can think of right now is that your `en.yml` file is missing the `format:` attribute I described in my answer. Or it's malformed.

Comment: On second thought. If for some reason your API gem/technology/technique expects you to raise a runtime error to report validation errors back to the user, then I guess you should to that. If that's the case, then let me know and we'll see what to do there.

Comment: Thanks for update. I am starting to suspect that the full_messages being blank is what is causing most or all of my issue. For now, I can am bypassing this issue via just grabbing the error message like so: `error.record.errors.messages.values[0][0]` which works with small alterations whether I use the rescue block method or or save without bang method.